# Chrome Extension to load local page with inline JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've created a chrome extension and build a help documentation using an online tool called Documenter by Revaxarts (example here: http://documenterdocs.revaxarts.com/doc_ca71f4007fd2ed01997a40c61d345e3f/)

This help document have all the instructions about the extension: what it is, how does it work and so on. I'd like to share this help document along with my extension (local files) and make it accessible by a "Help Guide" button on the popup menu (open in a new tab/window).

The problem is that the HTML file generated by the tool uses some inline javascript inside the `HTML <head></html>`, and since I'm on early stages of programming and it's my first attempt with chrome extensions, I can't seem to find a way to make this work, or even information if this is not possible at all.

The help guide file structure is this:

```
rootfolder/asssets/
roofolder/index.html
```

Where `/assets/` have CSS, JS and Imgs files.

I read some of the [External content](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#top), but I'm not quite sure how and even if it's possible to adapt to my needs. Maybe using sandbox? I didn't understand much about that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By default, [inline scripts will not be executed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution).

To relax this policy, see [Relax default policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution).

> Up until **Chrome 45**, there was **no mechanism** for relaxing the restriction against executing inline JavaScript. In particular, setting a script policy that includes 'unsafe-inline' will have no effect.
>
> As of **Chrome 46**, inline scripts can be whitelisted by specifying the base64-encoded hash of the source code in the policy. This hash must be prefixed by the used hash algorithm (sha256, sha384 or sha512). See **[Hash usage for  elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-CSP2-20150721/#script-src-hash-usage)** for an example.

However, I would suggest you extracted the inline scripts to an external scripts, for example, changing inline listeners such as `onclick=xxx` to `Element.addEventListener('click')`

Comment: Hey Haibara, thanks for the clarification. Reading your post I gave it a try on creating a button to the index.html file inside the extension and I think it worked. When I click the button, the page loads in a new tab no problem. Since I guess this is a page packed along with the extension, local file and will not be used in any content script or whatever, there's no problem on having inline Javascript.